# Can I travel from LA to NY with my foreign Passport? (it does not have a visa)

Tags: visas, legal

So I came to the US with a visa but overstayed so I became (illegal?). Im currently in the process of becoming a resident (my mom is a citizen) but am still waiting on my papers. I am traveling to NY in a week but I want to make sure that I can travel with my passport from a different country. 
My old passport (which expired) had my visa but since I renewed my passport it doesn't have a visa. Can I travel with my new passport even though it has no visa or anything besides my name and picture?

Am I taking a BIG risk here? Btw im 19.

Comment: The airline may not care, but if for any reason (random check, security scare etc) you come to the attention of airport police or Immigration you might face some difficult questions if you’re asked about your status.

Comment: Did you *keep* the expired passport with the visa? That will show you overstayed but did not enter illegally.

Comment: But I do have the right to remain silent don't i? Or do I have to answer whatever it is that they're asking?

Comment: I kept my passport with the old visa. I'll take that one as well in case they ask but wouldn't that be a problem? Since I am here illegally?

Comment: The CBP just agreed that passengers deplaning from domestic flights may not be required to show citizenship ID or visas wholesale. Your chances of getting caught are minimal. The airline check-in is unlikely to care about your visa status. They just want to check your photo. However, are you certain you are present illegally? Your pending application may, in some circumstances, entitle you to remain until it is decided. Check with whichever attorney or charity helped you prepare it.

Comment: When you say that you are "currently in the process of becoming a resident", do you mean that you have a filed and pending Adjustment of Status (I-485) application? or do you mean something else? If you have a pending I-485, you should bring the I-485 receipt with you in case you the unlikely scenario of running into the CBP.

Comment: @user102008 i am filling the I-485 to file soon, but that is actually an excellent idea!!! Thank you very much!